# Fill new column with yes if date has june else no

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a situation in pandas dataframe where if date has June month then in new column print yes else no for other months

Date format 2019-06-01

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided any details or sample dataframe, we can all only guess at what will actually work for your use-case. This solution assumes your `"Date"` column is the `datetime` type:

```py
df["new"] = df.where(df["Date"].dt.month == 6, "yes", "no")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def haveJune(row):
    if (row['Date'].str.contains('June').any()):
        val = 'Y'
    else:
        val = 'N'
    return val

df['new'] = df.apply(haveJune, axis=1)
```